# How can I display windows login form purely for authenticating a users account in VB6?

Tags: windows, vb6

We have an older **VB6** application that used to run under various user's accounts. We had to move it to a 'public' machine where multiple users use the same account, which is logged in automatically.

Is there a way to pop-up the official windows authentication form, have the users enter their credentials and pass me back a status weather or not authentication occurred or failed?

I could have the users enter in their username/password into a form created by myself and use the attached code to validate authentication. The problem is that this just looks sketchy to begin with, and I'd rather not have potential access to users passwords.

Here is the code I can use to authenticate a user:

```
on error resume next
strUserName = "username"
strPassword = "password"
strADsPath = "WinNT://domainname"
iFlags = "0"

' bind to the ADSI object and authenticate Username and password 
Set oADsObject = GetObject(strADsPath)
strADsNamespace = left(strADsPath, instr(strADsPath, ":"))

set oADsNamespace = GetObject(strADsNamespace)
Set oADsObject = oADsNamespace.OpenDSObject(strADsPath, "domainname\" & strUserName, strPassword, 0)

If not (Err.number = 0) Then
    MsgBox(strUserName + " Failed.")
Else
    MsgBox(strUserName + " Authenticated.")
End If
```

I am hoping for something like thus:

```
if (AuthenticateUser() <> true)
    MsgBox(strUserName + " Failed.")
Else
    MsgBox(strUserName + " Authenticated.")
End If
```

Comment: Could you specify the OS of the public workstation?

Comment: Poping up that window would be easy (not elegant) simply by sending keys Windows+L using KeybEvent API, but i don't understand something that would come after this: Suppose you popup Windows authentication Window and then the user selects that account that logs in automatically (the one used by many users), after this, if you ask Windows if authentication failed or not, it will always tell you the user is authenticated, in fact any user using Windows is authenticated or else Windows itself wouldn't allow the user to continue, could you explain how would you solve this?

Comment: The users do not know the password of the account their logging into. It's logged in automatically, so they wouldn't be able to authenticate using the common account anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a small stub executable that just runs the main one with `ShellExecute()` and the `"runas"` verb/operation. This should cause windows to prompt for the username/password to run as. This may limit the access they have interact with other applications though.

Comment: How can this be done programatically? Using shell execute with the runas verb that is. I can kind of envision this otherwise.

Comment: Erm, by calling `ShellExecute()` with the `runas` verb. There isn't any other way to call it.

Comment: Oh okay.. so I can use runas instead of open in the lpOperation parameter. I see now thanks for the direction.

Comment: Ah yeah, the function definition calls it `lpOperation`, then goes on to call it a verb.